# Applying Bayes rule

Tags: bayes

This is probably almost standard textbook Bayes rule, but I wanted to double check a formula that I am applying:

$P(A | B,C) = P(A|C) \cdot \frac{P(B|A,C)}{P(B|C)}$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's correct.

$$P(A | B,C) = P(A|C) \cdot \frac{P(B|A,C)}{P(B|C)}$$

Expand:

$$P(A | B,C)=\frac{P(A,C)}{P(C)}\cdot\frac{\frac{P(B,A,C)}{P(A,C)}}{\frac{P(B,C)}{P(C)}}$$

And then remove like terms:

$$P(A | B,C) = \frac{P(B,A,C)}{P(B,C)}$$

Rearrange:

$$P(A | B,C) = \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A | B,C) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B\cap C)} = \frac{P(A \vert B, C)P(B \vert C)P(C)}{P(B \vert C)P(C)}$$

Comment: When one algebraically cancels repeated factors on the right hand side, the left hand side reappears, suggesting this series of equations is trivial.  Is the OP's formula correct or not?

Comment: Yes,following this logic, $P(A|B,C)=\frac{P(A|B,C)xyz}{xyz}$ and all.